# Difficulty fetching json data from API using Angular

Tags: json, angular, api

I am trying to fetch data from API  https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json

and store them in table in my Angular Application. Initial 15 rows are displayed on my page, not all the rows. And I cannot fetch line data which is nested inside outcome object.

Here is my HTML code

```
  <div class="row">

<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Welcome!</span>
</mat-toolbar>


<div class="container">
  <br>
  <h2>Information</h2>  

    <span class="right"><a href="https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json" title="sportsbook1">API endpoint</a></span>     

   <table class="table  table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>HomeTeamName</th>
        <th>AwayTeamName</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Offers</th>
        <th>Line</th>

        <!--<th>Image</th>-->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let data of data.events">
      <tr>
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
        <td>{{data.name }}</td>
        <td>{{data.homeTeamName }}</td>
        <td>{{data.awayTeamName}}</td>
        <td>{{data.startDate }}</td>
        <td>{{data.offers[1].label }}</td>
          <td>{{data.offers.outcomes[2].line }}        

        <!--<td><img class="image-width" src="{{contact.image}}" alt="{{contact.name}}}"></td>-->

      </tr>
    </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my typescript code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-draftking',
  templateUrl: './draftking.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./draftking.component.css']
})
export class DraftkingComponent implements OnInit {
 private apiUrl = 'https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json';
  displayedColumns = ['id','name', 'homeTeamName','awayTeamName','offers','line'];
  data: any = {};
  dataSource = this.data;

 constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.getLeague1();
  this.getData1();

 }


getData1(){
 return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}

getLeague1() {
  this.getData1().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.data = data
  })
}
 ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Why you dont work with the service layer for API calls?

Comment: I am not sure how they works, could you explain a bit?

Answer (score 2):

Typically you setup your actual server call in a service (called model because it models your data). Here is one of mine as an example.

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public get<T>(path: string, routerParams?: Params): Observable<T> {
        let queryParams: Params = {};
        if (routerParams) {
            queryParams = this.setParameter(routerParams);
        }
        return this.http.get<T>(this.path(path), { params: queryParams });
    }

    public put<T>(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put(this.path(path), body);
    }

    public post<T>(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.path(path), body);
    }

    public delete<T>(path: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete(this.path(path));
    }
    ...
```

In my components (sometimes other services) I will call an API method and expect results in the form of an Observable. So in your case I'd use my service like this:

component

```
constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService('https://pathtoserver').subscribe(data => {
        if (data.id) {
            this.setCurrentUser();
        }
    });
}
```

Hey remember to NOT call getData1(); more than once or you'll have 2 "hot" subscriptions. Use `.pipe(take(1)).sub`... in order to end subscriptions once they give you something.

Comment: Should I create new component? How should and where should I make connection between service and my pages? Could you please provide more information?

Comment: So each component uses a model, view and controller file. I personally would create a service for making calls to outside servers like draftkings. Then in your component's 'constructor' you do what I show and call your service method which returns you an observable. I highly recommend Max on Udemy. He's great and the whole course is $9. https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check it out. In ngOnInit - Do I have to use `.map((res: Response) => res.json())`   ?

Comment: No, new Angular versions make sure return values are Json :) good question though.